# How to display the elements of my list ListNote in a card I do not know the syntax

Tags: flutter, dart

**here is my class model**

do not pay attention to hivefield and hivetype

I know how to read the data from my Patient list but not from ListNote which is in my Patient list

```
import 'package:hive_flutter/hive_flutter.dart';

part 'listpatient.g.dart';

@HiveType(typeId: 0)
class Patients {
  @HiveField(0)
  final String? name;

  @HiveField(1)
  final String? firstname;

  @HiveField(3)
  final String? dateofbirth;

  @HiveField(4)
  final String? email;

  @HiveField(5)
  final String? numero;

  @HiveField(6)
  final DateTime? date;

  @HiveField(7)
  final int? id;

  @HiveField(8)
  final List<ListNote>? listOfNotes;

  const Patients({
    this.name,
    this.firstname,
    this.dateofbirth,
    this.email,
    this.numero,
    this.date,
    this.id,
    this.listOfNotes,
  });
}

@HiveType(typeId: 0)
class ListNote {
  @HiveField(1)
  final String? title;

  @HiveField(2)
  final String? note;

  @HiveField(3)
  final String? conclusion;

  ListNote({
    this.title,
    this.note,
    this.conclusion,
  });
}
```

here is the code where I try to read my information

```
 _body() {
    return Column(
      children: <Widget>[
        Expanded(
          child: ListView(children: [
            Card(child: Text(widget.patients.listOfNotes.)) <------ Here
          ]),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
```

patients comes from the parent it patients contains the list

```
widget.patients.listOfNotes
```

**thank you for your help**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ID for the Patient and ListNote shouldn't be the same.

```
@HiveType(typeId: 0)
class Patients {
```

```
@HiveType(typeId: 0)
class ListNote {
```

and here,

```
 _body() {
    return Column(
      children: <Widget>[
        Expanded(
          child: ListView(children: [
            Card(child: Text(widget.patients.listOfNotes.)) <-- // it is list
          ]),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
```

You can access it like

```
children: [         // since this is a list.
  ...widget.patients.listOfNotes.map((e) -> Card(child: Text(e.title)))
]
```

if still have doubts and didn't work well, please paste your error message.

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly what I needed,

And thank you for the correction of the HiveType I thought that since it was part of the same list it would have the same id but no apparently thank you

Answer (score 1):

You can use spread operator.

```dart
children: [
  ...widget.patients.listOfNotes.map((e) -> Card(child: Text(e.title)))
]
```